# MAX time with IF NOT OR function

Tags: excel, if-statement

My data as per below.
I am trying the find the latest time in column B, given column D criteria whereby it is not `SYSTEM` OR `VOID`.

| Staff ID | Time | Date | Staff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |  |
| 34565 | 9:00:35 AM | 02/05/2023 | SYSTEM |
| 23586 | 5:32:05 AM | 05/05/2023 | SYSTEM |
| 46354 | 4:15:35 AM | 05/05/2023 | ALEX |
| 46546 | 4:09:30 AM | 06/05/2023 | CLARE |
| 98744 | 2:54:18 AM | 12/05/2023 | JOHN |
| 34534 | 3:23:10 AM | 20/05/2023 | SANDY |
| 87675 | 4:32:09 AM | 21/05/2023 | MANDA |
| 35645 | 7:15:23 AM | 26/05/2023 | VOID |
| 23423 | 6:15:23 AM | 08/05/2023 | ALEX |
| 23423 | 3:46:15 AM | 09/05/2023 | KEN |
| 34564 | 7:08:23 AM | 08/05/2023 | KEAT |

I tried to use the formula: `=MAX(IF(NOT(OR(D3:D13="SYSTEM",D3:D13="VOID")),B3:B13))` 
however it returns `12:00:00 AM` which is not the desired result, `7:08:23 AM`.

What is wrong with my formula?

Comment: What is your excel version?

Comment: What about dates?

Comment: @Harun24hr my excel version is Office 2021. I would like to try the formula on column B (time) solely first.

Comment: Can you please give a try to my answer.

Comment: it worked! how if I want to include date condition, and use Excel 2019?

Comment: If you do not have `MAXIFS()` in `EXCEL-2019` then try this array formula `=MAX((B2:B12)*(D2:D12<>"SYSTEM")*(D2:D12<>"VOID"))`. Array means confirm the formula with `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `EXCEL-2021` should have `MAXIFS()` function. Try-

```
=MAXIFS(B2:B12,D2:D12,"<>SYSTEM",D2:D12,"<>VOID")
```

Comment: it worked. thanks! what about if I used Excel 2019?

Comment: Either trying it or checking Microsoft Help for the `MAXIFS` function should answer that question.